# windows partition restored on specific date (unusual)

Tags: windows, windows-10, backup, restore, partition-recovery

This is a super unusual issue we have encountered, a PC of our payroll staff displayed an error upon opening today (05/11/2022). --MM/dd/YYYY
[see error upon opening the unit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvuqE.jpg)

Tried to restart the unit and it booted up properly, but to her surprise that her desktop are restored to her previous layout (she just re-arranged her desktop files and folders recently), and all of her new files are missing.

I tried to check on the event viewer and found out that the last event logged is last 11/02/2021
before todays event (05/11/2022).
[see event log after restarting and checking the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2FxZ.jpg)

I checked the system restore point, and the system restore is turned-off. (sorry forgot to take a screenshot).

I tried to recover her files using recuva but the files detected by the unit are until 11/02/2021 only. (scan for desktop only as she only saved her files on desktop)
[see recuva basic scan for file recovery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViR1Y.jpg)

I also tried the deep scan of recuva for desktop only and files detected are until 11/02/2021 only (sorry i forgot to take screenshot of deep scan).

I have checked the files on her other partition (D:), which has automatic backup of an application to this seperate drive at 2AM, but the latest backup file is on 05/10/2022 2:00AM, so it is possible that the unit gets the error on 05/10/2022 after 6PM since she got out at 6PM as the application backup on 5/11/2022 2:00AM didn't occurs.

Her unit is Windows10 Pro-64bit, core I7 920, and 512GB SSD as windows drive

In summary: only windows partition is restored to specific date 11/02/2021.

My questions are:

1. How is this scenario can occur, technically or layman. I just want to know how this pnenomenon can occur.
2. Is there a way we can restore her files from 11/02/2022 to 05/11/2022?

PS: We are working at the hospital, and we are just joking that she has an invisible friend thats pranking her, just to let her disappointment lighten up even a bit.

EDIT:

Moved the answer to edit as stated by sir @Ramhound. Thanks

This is in response to sir @user1686.

Upon checking, it is booting up from the old hard drive that is still connected to the unit before I changed it up to SSD on 11/02/2021 (cloned Drive C to SSD).

I didn't removed the old drive before as the drive D of the old Drive is used as application backup, I just removed the drive letter of the old Drive C for her not to be able to see the old drive.

Which is the cause of this issue. To avoid this on happening again I reformatted the old drive C (HDD).

Again thank you sir @user1686 for bringing it up.

Comment: Are you sure it's booting from the SSD it's supposed to boot from? Is the other partition (D:) on the same SSD or on a separate disk?

Comment: Thank you for bringing it up sir. Upon checking, it is booting up from the old hard drive that is still connected to the unit before I changed it up to SSD on 11/02/2021 (cloned Drive C to SSD). I didn't removed the old drive before as the drive D of the old Drive is used as application backup, I just removed the drive letter of the old Drive C for her not to be able to see the old drive. Will post this as answer so this question can be closed. Thanks

Comment: Ah, so you have the same habit of "just leave the old disk in" as my old coworker did... some of the computers here had three disks, all with copies of the same OS.

Comment: Unfortunately, Yes. haha. I will fix this habit now. Thanks again sir.

Comment: @Ramhound: Why are you telling users to post their own answers in the question? That's the exact opposite of how the site works.